# About the cardinality of sigma algebra and power set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. We know that $|\mathcal{P}(X)|=2^{|X|}$.

Let $\mathcal{K}=\{A_{1},\dots,A_{n}\}$, where $A_{1},\dots,A_{n}$ are subsets of $X$.

**Question**: Is it true that $|\sigma(\mathcal{K})|=|\mathcal{P}(X)|$?

Was inspired by the solution manual of [Schilling's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521615259) to Problem 3.4 (ii).

Comment: @User1006: The set theory and elementary set theory tags are supposed to be disjoint. And certainly, this is not a question which merits the advanced tag. (And the fact that all of these questions have your answers to them is frankly quite suspicious.)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely no.

If $n=1$, then $\sigma(\cal K)$ is just $\{\varnothing,A,X\setminus A,X\}$. Regardless of anything about $X$. So if $X$ is anything larger than two elements, this will not be the same size as $\mathcal P(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

A finitely generated $\sigma$-algebra is always finite.  Indeed, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of unions of sets of the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i$, where each $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or its complement.  Then it is not hard to show $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{K}$, and hence is equal to $\sigma(\mathcal{K})$.  There are at most $2^n$ sets of the form $\bigcap B_i$, so there are at most $2^{2^n}$ elements of $\sigma(\mathcal{K})$.

Comment: This is just a sanity check. In the countably generated case, it is not true in general that $\mathcal{A}=\sigma({\mathcal{K}})$. It remains true that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but not $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{A}$. The failure that arises is that in the finite case, we could write (for each $j$) $A_j$ as a union of all sets of the form $\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} B_k$ where $B_j=A_j$. This union is finite. But in the countable case, there are *continuum* many sets of the form $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$ where $B_j=A_j$, so their union isn't necessarily contained in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Well, it depends how you define $\mathcal{A}$.  If you define $\mathcal{A}$ as the set of *arbitrary* unions of sets of the form $\bigcap B_k$ then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, but the problem is that $\sigma(\mathcal{K})$ may be smaller than $\mathcal{A}$ since it does not have to be closed under those arbitrary unions.  If you instead define $\mathcal{A}$ to consist of only countable unions of such sets, then $\mathcal{A}$ is not even a $\sigma$-algebra: it isn't closed under complements!

Answer (score 0):

Accually, $|\sigma(\mathscr{B})|=|\mathcal{P}(\aleph_0)|=\mathbb{c}$, i.e. $\sigma$-algebra on Borel set on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{c}$ (continuum), which is the same as $\mathbb{R}$, not the $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma(\mathbb R)$?  The question makes no mention of Borel sets, nor even of topology.  It is a purely set-theoreitc question.

Comment: I just give a counter example that $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ (Borel set) is $\mathbb{c}$, same as $\mathbb{R}$, not the $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The notation $\sigma(\cal K)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated *by* the family of subsets of $X$, $\cal K$, not *some* $\sigma$-algebra on the set $\cal K$. So $\sigma(\Bbb R)$ makes very little sense.